# What is the name of this orange flower?

Tags: identification, flowers

This is an orange/yellow flower. The image is not taken by me, so I can't give much more detail other than what can be seen.

[image]

Comment: see answer (changed my mind about a comment!)

Answer (score 2):

This is difficult to ID - there are loads of yellow/orange daisy type flowers, we can't see inside the flower, don't know the height of the plant, where its  growing, and can't see much of the foliage.

All that said, my guess is Calendula officinalis, common name English Marigold, a darkish orange variety shown here http://worldoffloweringplants.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Calendula-officinalis-Pot-Marigold2.jpg

Comment: Agreed. The few non-flower parts that are in focus (e.g. the beginning of a seed head and a few leaves) confirm your id.